# What Tooltip System does Stack Exchange use for its tag tooltips? (popover)

Tags: discussion, tags, tooltips

I have a website that has a tag cloud and I'd like to create a tooltip system that works exactly like the one on Stack Exchange.

On Stack Exchange if you hover on a tooltip you'll get the following tooltip:

> [image: tooltip screen shot]

Does anyone know if Stack Exchange uses a particular jQuery library or something to do this?

Comment: I believe that is a poput and not really a tool tip. You can achieve this by using divs and populating them and showing them on user keyboard or mouse events.

Comment: These popups are one of the most obnoxious items I've ever encountered on a website. They are constantly getting "stuck" open. They fire off an XMLHTTP request every time one pops up. Luckily, they can be disabled using AdBlock Plus. Please do not even think of spreading this cancer!

Answer (score 1):

This is custom JavaScript code using jQuery, which is creating the contents `<div>` on the fly and put it in the proper position.

It's called `MagicPopup` and you can view the source in the [main JavaScript file](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/js/full.js?v=d42020c0e528).

As for using it yourself, I'm not sure how legal this is.